DEVELOPER_ERROR in loadPaymentData: An error occurred in call back, please try to avoid this by setting structured error in callback response
I am attempting to create a google pay button with react however when I try and place an order i get the below error.

DEVELOPER_ERROR in loadPaymentData: An error occurred in call back, please try to avoid this by setting structured error in callback response

    <GooglePayButton
      environment="TEST"
      paymentRequest={{
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        allowedPaymentMethods: [
          {
            type: "CARD",
            parameters: {
              allowedAuthMethods: ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
              allowedCardNetworks: ["MASTERCARD", "VISA"],
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: {
              type: "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
              parameters: {
                gateway: "",
                gatewayMerchantId: "",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        merchantInfo: {
          merchantId: "", // Replace with your merchant ID
          merchantName: "",
        },
        transactionInfo: {
          totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
          totalPriceLabel: "Total",
          totalPrice: order ? order.total_price : "0",
          currencyCode: "ZAR", // South African Rand
          countryCode: "ZA", // South Africa
        },
        shippingAddressRequired: true,
        callbackIntents: ["SHIPPING_ADDRESS", "PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"],
      }}
      onLoadPaymentData={(paymentRequest) => {
        console.log("Success", paymentRequest);
      }}
      onPaymentAuthorized={handleGooglePaySuccess}
      onPaymentDataChanged={(paymentData) => {
        console.log("On Payment Data Changed", paymentData);
        return {};
      }}
      existingPaymentMethodRequired="false"
      buttonColor="black"
      buttonType="Buy"
    />

The error code in google UI

Your onLoadPaymentData isn't returning anything. Your onPaymentDataChanged is returning at least {}.
